# Passing enum variable to a function

Tags: c, enums

Hi I have a function below.

```
void turnRight(enum Direction heading, int x, int y){

if(y<=49 && heading==TORIGHT){
    heading=TODOWN;
    x=x+1;

}
else if(x<=49 && heading==TODOWN){
    heading=TOLEFT;
    y=y-1;
}
else if(x>0 && heading==TOLEFT){
    heading=TOUP;
    x=x-1;
}
else if(y<=49&&heading==TOUP){
    heading=TORIGHT;
    y=y+1;
}

else 
    printf("Can not turn right! Boundary alert!");

}//end function
```

I declared enum in main as:

```
enum Direction {TODOWN, TOUP, TORIGHT, TOLEFT};
static enum Direction heading;
heading=TORIGHT;
```

and I am calling this function from main with

```
turnRight(heading, x, y);
```

and above all I added prototype as:

```
  void turnRight(enum Direction heading, int x, int y);
```

but compiler spits below errors all over:

```
error C2065: 'TODOWN' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'TOUP' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'TOLEFT' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'TORIGHT' : undeclared identifier
```

can you tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: if both functions are in the same file, just declare your enum at the beginning, before both functions, otherwise, see answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I declared enum in main

You need to declare `enum Direction` in a file that is included in all translation units that use the `enum`, not only in `main`. For example, you can define it in `Direction.h` (don't forget to add the [inclusion guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)), and then include it in both your `main` and the turn-processing source files:

Direction.h

```
#ifndef Direction_H
#define Direction_H

enum Direction {TODOWN, TOUP, TORIGHT, TOLEFT};

#endif
```

Now add `#include "Direction.h"` to your `main` and other files using the `enum` to make your sources compile correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your enum before any of your functions, in the global scope (ie. outside of any function).  Otherwise it will only be visible in the function you declare it in.  If your functions live in different `.c` files, you need to put the enum into a header file.